# Regular Expression preg_match() for hreflang

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on `php script` to output a number of `hreflang` tags based on the page the user is on. Currently I am using `preg_match()` to match the URL being requested again a specific pattern. If it matches output the relevant tags...

So I've got something like this:

```
<?php if (preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company/i", $url)): ?>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/en-gb/company/" hreflang="en-gb" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/company/" hreflang="en" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/company/" hreflang="x-default" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

when I visit the page `www.mydomain1.com/en-gb/company` it outputs the  above tags. I also have another URL `www.mydomain1.com/en-gb/company/stats`. So I wrote another block for this URL:

```
   <?php if (preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company\/stats/i", $url)): ?>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/en-gb/company/stats" hreflang="en-gb" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/company/stats" hreflang="en" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mydomain1.com/company/stats" hreflang="x-default" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

However this page will output all of the `hreflangtags`from the first `if statement` and never enters the second. I know my `regular Expression` is wrong but I can't pinpoint exactly where. I'd appreciate any help in order to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may restrict the first regex to avoid matching `en-gb/company` when followed with `/stats` using a negative lookahead:

```
preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company(?!\/stats(?:\/|$))/i", $url)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xanals/1)

The `(?!\/stats(?:\/|$))` negative lookahead will fail all matches of `/en-gb/company` that are followed with `/stats/` or `/stats` at the end of the input.

Note that in case you just want to check an *entire* path with the first regex, you may use [Paladin76 approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40868151/3832970) by adding the `$` end-of-string anchor, but I'd also add an optional `/` at the end:

```
preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company\/?$/i", $url)
                              ^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xanals/2)

Now, this pattern will only match inputs that are only equal to `/en-gb/company` or `/en-gb/company/`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, It seems good - One question in relation to it... If I have numerous child pages so for example `/company/about` and `/company/contact` etc do I need to add multiple `negative lookaheads`???

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to exclude. If you just want to match the `/en-gb/company` that is at the end of the input with the first regex, use Paladin's solution (maybe a bit modified as `preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company\/?$/i", $url)`). But yes, you can add alternatives: `(?!\/(?:stats|contact|etc)(?:\/|$))`

Answer (score 2):

Try it with the end operator `$` like this:

```
<?php if (preg_match("/^\/en-gb\/company\/$i", $url)): ?>
```

So, in your code, everytime, your url **starts** with en-gb/company it will hit your first code. Your second url also starts with en-gb/company, so you need to tell the matching, that it ends after company to go into your code.